# Xamarin Binding issue

Tags: xamarin

I Have a list with grouping enabled .

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Allgroups}" IsGrouped="True" >
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"></GridItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Categories[0].NameNative}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding TitleWithItemCount}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Notice 
if i remove the [0] and made it like this Categories.NameNative nothing will show . if i kept it as is it will only show the first item of each group .

[image]

Comment: if Categories is a List then it doesn't have any direct properties.  Please post the code for `Allgroups`

Comment: @Jason would the image included help ? otherwise ill have different means to share the code

Comment: All groups have List < Services > and inside the object Services there is a list < Categories >

Comment: please read the docs on grouping - you need to have the data grouped a certain way for this to work.  You can't just use nested IEnumerables.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#group-data

Comment: @Jason thanks , it worked !